# a reminder service that finds everything that is due within a week.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

the code below gets me what will be due in exactly one week from today, but I want it to show me everything that will be due before the week is up. How do I modify it to show me what is due in not only a week but also what is due less than a week?

```
def self.get_due_today
  RenewalReminder.where(:duedate => Date.today7.days)
end
```

Comment: Could be as easy as `Date.today + 7`, but please explain what you have already tried.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers is correct but for readability i would make it `Date.today + 7.days` or `Date.today + 1.week`. I think it makes it more obvious even though the results are identical.

Comment: @engineersmnky Agreed

Comment: In Rails there is `7.days.from_now` or `1.week.from_now`

Comment: my project team at school have figure out that much that we need to have addition of 7 days added to the code but we get errors or our display code will no longer display anything  <% RenewalReminder.get_due_today.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.vehicleid %> <br/>
<% end %>
</br>

Comment: @VuVan please edit your question and add the relevant code / errors

Comment: the code works but it only shows what will be due in a week. How do I get it to show everything that is due up to 7 days?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for:

```
RenewalReminder.where('duedate <= ?', 7.days.from_now)
```

Comment: This gives me an error at the display code <% RenewalReminder.get_due_today.each do |r| %>

Comment: @Siddharth I'm confused, are you talking to me?  He asked how to get everything up to 7 days from now, how does that not answer the question?

Comment: @VuVan What is the error you are getting from using this?

Comment: Review error. Thanks for pointing it out. Also a upvote deserved.